# Highcharts Stock Double Click support on Navigator

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Im currently working on some charts using the highcharts library(stock), however I was wondering if there is way I can achieve the double click on the navigator section, I want to click on a section of the navigator and be able to set the extreme(either left-right) depending on the side they have done the click I've been looking different approaches but it looks like this can't be done any ideas?...thanks!

I've try using this library that supports custom events , but there is not custome vent for the navigator section https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you wrote, the custom events library does not support double click on the navigator.

What you want to implement looks like quite custom functionality. I tried using the API and overriding some navigator methods but without any satisfactory effect.

I would suggest submitting this as a feature request on the Highcharts GitHub repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose